# Случайная выборка из генеральной савокупности средствами Excel

Tags: excel, макросы

Помогите, пожалуйста, прописать формулу для формирования выборки из таблицы Excel. Задача состоит в том чтобы выбрать целые строки (в заданном количестве штук) в случайном порядке, но по нескольким критериям. Чтобы они вырезались в отдельный лист - и после проверки (обзвона клиентов) - можно было их вернуть назад.

Создал тестовую таблицу, где листы:
1. Генеральная савокупность
2. Сводная таблица
3. Параметры по которым нужно сделать выборку - и количество строк - сколько нужно выбрать

[ТАБЛИЦА](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rVf2neWQXZ_EFO60UnmJ6CNoBZIzS0gQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Какая ещё формула? Это только макросом делается.

Comment: Можете помочь с макросом?

Comment: Что, сделать ЗА ВАС этот макрос? Тогда Вы немного ошиблись, это Вам к фрилансерам. А если Вы намерены сами его делать - делайте. И уже с конкретными узкими проблемами приходите сюда - кто-нибудь непременно поможет.

Comment: Поправка: это делается не макросом - макросами :) У Вас ТЗ, а не вопрос по проблеме. Обращайтесь...

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. Буду разбираться. Задачка вообщем не простая...